# Setting up virtual environment in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

i just started learning django and i am very confused in how to set up a virtual environment.

i have successfully installed python:

When i run `python --version` i get
`Python 3.8.1`

and when i run `python3 --version` i get
`Python 3.8.1`

My first problem is when i run `which -a  python3` i get this

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`

`/usr/local/bin/python3`

`/usr/bin/python3`

Can someone help me understand why i have 3 locations where python3 exist?

My 2nd problem is i have successfully installed `virtaulenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`

when i run `virtualenv --version` i get:

`virtualenv 20.4.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py`

and when i run `virtualenvwrapper --version` i get:

`-bash: virtualenvwrapper: command not found`

thats why when i run `mkvirtualenv test` i keep getting command not found.

My third problem is what is the difference between `virtualenv test` and `mkvirtualenv test`?

Comment: So if you go to `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin/` ... and list python3... you will find that there is a soft link. These all python3 will link to the same binary python.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha what do you mean by list python3 to find a soft link?

Comment: you just can do `ls -ld python3` ... in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin/` path...

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha for  `/usr/local/bin` i get `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  69 26 Jan  2020 python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3` and for `/usr/bin/` i get `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31488 22 Sep  2020 python3` they are not the same, why?

Comment: so you have two different python3. `/usr/bin` is distribution managed. `/usr/local/bin` is not a distribution managed, but a locally package installation. It is not recommended to install your local packages in `/usr/bin` otherwise it some updates on distribution managed will be impacted... Now if you do `echo $PATH`. you will see that `/usr/local/bin` will come before `/usr/bin`.. so that you can use you local package, and if local package is not found then system will take it from `/usr/local` i.e. from distribution manager.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha do you think that happened because i installed python from python website and then again using homebrew?

Comment: Yes... Its probably because of that... also you can check the time stamp of python at both the directory. for one its Jan 2020 and for other its Sep 2020...

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha should i remove one of the pythons installed? if yes which one and how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230296/discussion-between-shivendra-pratap-kushwaha-and-kd12345).

Comment: Too much misunderstanding. Please reread https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using Ubuntu you can follow the steps below**

1. Go to the folder where you intend to keep your Django project
2. Run the command `python -m venv env`
3. env is the name of virtual env if python doesn't work try with python3
4. activate environment by `source env/bin/activate` env is the name of environment.
5. Install all dependencies make a new folder and import Django project in it.

Comment: I am not using ubuntu, i am trying to install it on Mac Terminal

Comment: check the link you will find solution : https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-django-on-mac-or-linux/

Comment: this works even for mac I am using the same